# Random notification 

Tags: android

I am pretty new with android app development. I have a requirment in which I have to generate random reminder notification during the time set.

I dont know where to start from, what i need to look into for fullfiling the requriment - android services i guess but before going that route , i want to check with experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something done in the background on a regular basis, then yes, it has to be a service. Also there is another way of doing it (pointed out by **Pixie**) which would be using [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to launch your task at a scheduled time.

Comment: k thanks and what component i should look into for Time interval for notification, I will also appriciate if you can also point me to any existing open source in which similar stuff is happening ?

Comment: I think `AlarmManager` class will satisfy your needs.